# Wrapping full HTML page within another

Tags: php, html, email, imap

I am putting together a basic read only client for gmail, I'm successfully pulling emails via imap (in PHP) and storing them however I am hitting a few problems with displaying them in the browser.

Most emails are full html pages `<html><title>Your Mail</title><body>etc...</body></html>` which often cause breakage to the root html page that the emails are being displayed within.

For example you often end up with

```
<html>
<title>Read only mail>
<body>
<h1>Your mail:</h1>
<html><title>An email from steve</title><style>html {background-color=red;}</style>
<body>It's a read email! (get it?)</body></html>
<html><title>An email from james</title><style>body {background-color=green;}</style>
<body>I like green things, save the planet!</body></html>
More mail etc...
</body>
</html>
```

Which isn't completely valid html, but the main problem is that email's CSS affects all the other elements on the page, my best idea is to somehow make an iframe with PHP (is this possible without a further request), or somehow strip out all the CSS and HTML from the document.

Does anyone know how to get around this problem? How do gmail and other web clients do it?
Happy to look into client side solutions such as Javascript/jQuery & Ajax

Thanks for your time,

--

Currently the mail is just output as such:

```
/* connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die(imap_last_error());

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
if($emails) {

  /* begin output var */
  $output = '';

  /* put the newest emails on top */
  rsort($emails);

  /* for every email... */
  foreach($emails as $email_number) {

    /* get information specific to this email */
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

    /* output the email header information */
    $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
    $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
    $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
    $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
    $output.= '</div>';

    /* output the email body */
    $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
  }

  echo $output;
} 

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox)
```

Taken from http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap (my code is slightly different but with the same design & output)

Comment: use domDocument or such to extract whats between the body tag.

Comment: For this emails-within-a-page function, you could render the plaintext version of emails, rather than the HTML. That'd save you a great deal of hassle!

Comment: Any idea how you extract the plaintext version/how you request plaintext with imap?

Comment: Why can't you use an `<ifrmae>`? You can set the contents of an `<iframe>`.

Comment: If you can tell me how to set the content of an iframe with PHP great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here try this, with domDocument extract whats between the body tag of each of the messages:

```
<?php set_time_limit(0); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>You have mail</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
/* connect */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = '';
$password = '';
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die(imap_last_error());

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
if($emails){

    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';

    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);

    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {

        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox, $email_number, 0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 2);

        /* output the email header information */
        $output.= '<div class="toggler'.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
        $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
        $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
        $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
        $output.= '</div>';

        /* output only the email body */
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom->loadHTML($message);
        $body = $dom->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0);
        if ($body !== null) {
            for ($n = $body->firstChild; $n !== null; $n = $n->nextSibling) {
                $body = simplexml_import_dom($n)->asXML();
            }
        }
        $output.= '<div id="body">'.$body.'</div>';
    }

    echo $output.'
</body>
</html>';
}

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
?>
```

To answer your other question if you only want the plain text part of the email (tho this could also contain multipart boundaries)

Use `$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 1);` notice the `1`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pick out the elements you want to keep, like the body itself by php and drop the rest ? You certainly will need a switch to apply different rules for a set of basic email content layouts: But you gain the freedom to implement specific and reliable rules for each layout.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an iframe to display the message, or grab text inside body tag using regular expression server side or grab body element using dom client side.